# data not being inserted inside the database because of one column

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysqli

I have a mysqli/php code below where it is suppose to insert data into the 'Session' Table.

```
  ...

if (isset($_POST['textWeight'])) {

$_SESSION['textWeight'] = $_POST['textWeight'];

}

...

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

        {

            $time = str_replace(array(' Hrs ', ' Mins ', ' Secs'), array(':', ':', ''), $_SESSION['durationChosen']);

            for ($i = 1, $n = $_SESSION['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i) {

                    $insertsql = "
              INSERT INTO Session
                (SessionId, SessionTime, SessionDate, SessionWeight, SessionDuration, TotalMarks, ModuleId, TeacherId, Room)
              VALUES
                (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            ";
            if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
              // Handle errors with prepare operation here
            }

                $sessid = $_SESSION['id'] . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i);
                $sessdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['dateChosen']));

                $insert->bind_param("sssisisis", $sessid, $_SESSION['timeChosen'], $sessdate,
                             $_SESSION['textWeight'], $time, $_SESSION['textMarks'],
                             $_SESSION['module'], $teacherid, $_SESSION['rooms']);

                $insert->execute();

                if ($insert->errno) {
                  // Handle query error here
                }

                $insert->close();

            }
```

Problem I am getting is that it is not inserting any data into the database and the reason for this is because it is displaying this error below:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): (23000/1048): Column 'SessionWeight' cannot be null in /web/stud/..../.... on line 182
```

The values posted into the "SessionWeight" column comes from  `$_SESSION['textWeight']` But it should not display this error because I have stated that if user has clicked on "No" in the radio button below, then the value in the textbox is 0, else if the user selects "Yes" then the user must enter in their own figure (blank textbox not allowed).

```
//HTML
        <th>Provide a Total Weight Assessment is worth to Module?</th>
        <td><input type="radio" name="weightChoice" value="Yes" onClick="getWeight()" class="radioBtn"/> Yes</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="weightChoice" value="No" onClick="getWeight()" class="radioBtn"/> No</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="radioAlert"></div>
            <p></p>
        <table id="tblWeight">
        <tr>
        <th>Weight:</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtWeight" name="totalWeight" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="5" />%</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

....

```
//Javascript

        function getWeight() {
            var weightChoice = document.getElementsByName("weightChoice");               
            var textWeight = document.getElementById("txtWeight");
            var tblWeight = document.getElementById("tblWeight");

            if(weightChoice[0].checked == true){
                tblWeight.style.display = "block";
                textWeight.value = "";
            }else{
                tblWeight.style.display = "none";
                textWeight.value = 0;

        }

    }
```

The SessionWeight column in the database is a non-key field which data type is int(3)

Comment: What happens if javascript is disabled?  You need a client side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input field has `name="totalWeight"`, but you try to read `$_POST['textWeight']`

It looks like that's the problem

Comment: Oh my god, cannot believe I have done that and missed that. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah... your code seems to have lots of variables with different names used to keep same things or parts of information that should make up an object. You should work towards cleaner solutions or you'll miss something again soon. 
Also, I might be wrong with that, but from what you posted it seems like you misuse the $_SESSION for storing global variables.